# Dependencies errors using react-admin with ra-data-django-rest-framework

Tags: reactjs, django, react-admin

I created a new project using vite and installed react-admin. I have a backend in django so I want to use **ra-data-django-rest-framework**. But the issue is it's very old and when I try to install it's showing dependency error for react v16. Is there any alternative packages for this? I have REST api in django can I use some other data providers without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Django user so I'm not sure what kind of REST dialect it 'speaks', but basically I'd say you have two options here:

- Either tweak your API to speak the same [REST dialect](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest#rest-dialect) as the one expected by [ra-data-simple-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest)
- Or you can write your own dataProvider, specially crafted for your API. It's not as hard as you might think. To start, you can have a look at the [Example REST Implementation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderWriting.html#example-rest-implementation) from the docs. You may even end up helping others if you open source your implementation ️

Comment: I wrote one of my own but I'm getting strange issue. The props of my Lister component is always empty and even I tried useRecordContext which returns data key as null.
<Resource list={<Lister />} />